# Base class with a generic type which implements an interface with a generic type

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern, .net-4.6.2

I'm implementing a Repository pattern and I would like to `FooRepository` to be re-usable for all models that implement `IEntity` however the IDE (Rider) says that `Type parameter 'IEntity' hides interface 'IEntity'` and later one causes the error message `Cannot resolve symbol 'ID'` in the `GetById` method.

**What is the proper way to create a base class for generic types (`IEntity` in this case) that also implements an interface which takes the same generic class?**

The end goal is to re-use the `FooRepository` for other models (than `Bar`) as the methods such as `GetById` as they will mostly function the same between them.

```
public abstract class FooRepository<IEntity> : IRepository<IEntity>
{
    private List<IEntity> _data;

    public List<IEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return this._data;
    }

    public IEntity GetById(int id)
    {

        return this.GetAll().Single(c => c.ID == id);
    }
}

public class BarRepository : FooRepository<Bar>
{
}

public interface IEntity
{
    int ID { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository<IEntity>
{
    List<IEntity> GetAll();
    IEntity GetById(int id);
}

public class Bar : IEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your abstract class by using generics.

```
public abstract class FooRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T: IEntity
    {
        private List<T> _data;

        public List<T> GetAll()
        {
            return this._data;
        }

        T IRepository<T>.GetById(int id)
        {
            return this.GetAll().Single(c => c.ID == id);
        }
    }

    public class BarRepository : FooRepository<Bar>
    {
    }

    public interface IEntity
    {
        int ID { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IRepository<T>
    {
        List<T> GetAll();
        T GetById(int id);
    }

    public class Bar : IEntity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I do think a nicer (less complicated) solution is:

```
public abstract class FooRepository<T> where T: IEntity
    {
        private List<T> _data;

        public List<T> GetAll()
        {
            return this._data;
        }

        T GetById(int id)
        {
            return this.GetAll().Single(c => c.ID == id);
        }
    }

    public class BarRepository : FooRepository<Bar>
    {
    }

    public interface IEntity
    {
        int ID { get; set; }
    }


    public class Bar : IEntity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

You do not need the IRepository interface because your abstract class is covering this.

Comment: If the answer is to your liking please accept the answer.

Comment: I guess you're right, I was complicating things with both an abstract class and an interface